# Increasing the throttling in JBOSS log

Tags: logging, jboss, quarkus, rate-limiting, open-telemetry

I am facing an issue regarding the throttling on my application and I am not aware of any changes that can increase this limitation.

Applications runs on Quarkus Framework and has imported the following dependencies:

- openTelemetry
- jboss-logging

As far I understood, the rate limit can be override but there is a default of 10k messages per second but I would need to increase this value.

Any suggestions how to do it?